# What flies in the sky but is bound to earth?

Tags: riddle

> I fly in the sky,
>
> But am bound to the earth,
>
> The method is ashes.
>
> I scorch the surface,
>
> And warm the interior.
>
> I am the embodiment of a star,
>
> What is my name?

Comment: I see that the accepted answer was changed, is this intentional? Does this puzzle have an intended solution?

Comment: @floraline an intended *category* of solutions, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> A phoenix.
>  Phoenixes fly, they turn into ashes when dead, and rebirth from the ashes, phoenixes scorch (they are a flying fire), and they warn the interior by acting as handy home heating system (okay joking). There is also a constellation.

Answer (score 5):

You are

> A hydrogen bomb?

I fly in the sky,

> A bomb flies through the sky

But am bound to the earth,

> But is meant to hit the earth

The method is ashes.

> It will burn everything in it's wake

I scorch the surface,

> It definitely scorches the surface

And warm the interior.

> It gives off a lot of heat?

I am the embodiment of a star,

> Stars are made of hydrogen

What is my name?

> Hydrogen bomb

Answer (score 3):

I think you're:

> Fire.

I fly in the sky,
But am bound to the earth,

> The flames of a fire flicker in the sky, but it always has a base on earth (i.e. whatever thing is burning).

The method is ashes.

> Perhaps the "method" by which it's bound to the earth?  Not entirely sure...

I scorch the surface,
And warm the interior.

> Fire scorches things it touches, but can also be used to heat the interior of, say, a house (like in a fireplace).

I am the embodiment of a star,

> Stars are often called/ thought of as super-hot, gaseous balls of fire.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> lightning

I fly in the sky,

> Lightning is in the sky

But am bound to the earth,

> Bound to earth meaning lightning's path

The method is ashes.

> Lightning toasts whatever it interacts with

I scorch the surface,

> Lightning

And warm the interior.

> Lightning

I am the embodiment of a star,

> Stars are plasma, lightning is plasma

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> The atmosphere

I fly in the sky,

> Observed in and fills the sky

But am bound to the earth,

> The atmosphere does not escape the earth's gravity

The method is ashes.

> Our atmosphere was created by the eruption of volcanoes

I scorch the surface,

And warm the interior.

> Our atmosphere warms the planet by way of the greenhouse effect

I am the embodiment of a star,

> Stars are exploding balls of gas - our atmosphere is composed of gases

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> Magma or Lava

I fly in the sky,

> Volcanic eruption

But am bound to the earth,

> Literally, made of earth

The method is ashes.
I scorch the surface,

> Eruption, again

And warm the interior.

> Liquid magma in the earth's interior

I am the embodiment of a star,

> Very bright and very hot hot hot

What is my name?

> Magma

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Interesting answer! Though I think the second to last line is inaccurate

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> A balloon

I fly in the sky,
But am bound to the earth,

> Both helium and hot-air balloons fly, but both will eventually return to the ground.

The method is ashes.
I scorch the surface,
And warm the interior.

> Hot air balloons use fire in a burner to heat the air inside the balloon.

I am the embodiment of a star,

> Stars are usually thought of as being balls of fire and hot gasses.  Hot air balloons use fire (as described above) and contain hot gas/air.  If you include other types of balloons, helium is one of the primary gasses composing the sun.

Comment: All good answers...

Answer (score 2):

> A Volcano

Because

> Spewing ash and lava into the sky; A mountain bound to the earth; in the crater sits the interior (hot lava); ready to erupt and explode like a star